# Take a detailed model and make it suitable for 3D printing?

Tags: 3d-models

I have a model I would like to print, specifically it is a free-for-personal-use model of a car, complete with interior.

I would like to print it, but it is unprintable. I have tried to fix it in netfabb, which works OK. But now I realised I have another problem - the inside of the car is hollow, and has a full interior. I just want the shell of the car and a solid block (complete with opaque 'windows').

How would I take a detailed model and somehow extract a solid 3D printable model from it?

Comment: This is by no means an easy task, and requires decent CAD modelling skills. As an answer to this question would need to be basically an entire CAD tutorial, I've voted to close this as "too broad". You might be able to limit the scope of this question by considering just one 3d modelling package (as right now an answer could address one of a 100 modelling tools), but even then it is too broad in my opinion.

Comment: You're going to use a lot of unprintable words while dealing with this unprintable shape :-).   If you have a model w/ enough sub-elements, then just delete all the elements not visible from the outside.  At that point you *might* be able to slice and specify infill; most likely you'll need a bunch of support posts specified if you want a detailed undercarriage.

Comment: "unprintable words"  Nice.  :-)

Comment: James, what is your starting file format.  Is it an STL or other?  Maybe that will help narrow down your question and you can get a specific answer that will help.  Also, if the file is online, maybe you could add a link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend "The Maker's Muse" youtube video channel.

In particular this video [Fixing impossible STL's with Meshmixer 3.1.118 BETA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ECNP3WN_-Q) might solve your problem.

Few other videos which might help:

- [How to make Engineering Assemblies 3D Printable using Meshmixer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPUT_q8tcsM)
- [Add smoothness to your meshes using remeshing! 3D 101](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LeuX963jpn8)
- [A Detailed look at Processes and Profiles in Simplify3D](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oR-cToT8v-c)
- [Tidy up your prints with the Modifi3D](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwc1X6oInkc)
- [How to Print Bigger Things - 3D Printing 101](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afLolx2OEKE)